# Referencing data grid view in form to other data grid view in other form

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to the data in the data grid view to get copied to other grid view in other
Form, the problem is I can't, is it by defining global variable and make it equal to that data grid view and then make the other data grid view reference it when i click button or any other way ?

Comment: Please show an attempt at what you have tried and whats not working and where.

Comment: I tried to reference it from other form by making a public shared variable, but i can't access it so I search on how to make a global variable in vb, and it showed that I have to make a module to make a public variable, I don't know where to place my module ?

Comment: Show code, a module doesn't have anything to do with it either... You don't have to have it to reference something.

Comment: Then how I can make a public variable that is accessible to all forms ?

Comment: Create an instance of your form; you can pass it into all your other forms. Then you can do anything you want with them. It's a good practice to use **objects** you can pass around and use.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or a web page you can give me about that and post it as answer, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer with a quick Google search.

- [Passing objects to Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxa9y69d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Another great link about passing arguments ByVal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx)
- [Information about creating event's and delegates](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23020)

As said before, it's best to create an instance and pass that as an argument. Then inside your other class you have anything you need from it.